# using sed to write a shell script

Tags: shell

So, I want to read file from stdin, delete all '/' in line that contain exactly 3 '/', and write the output to stdout. So a file contain:

```
/a1/b/c
/a/b2
///
/a
```

will have output:

```
a1bc
/a/b2

/a
```

I am thinking something like this:

```
sed -r 's/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/.*/"I not sure what do I need to put in here"/g'
```

however, I am not really sure what do I need to put in the replace session.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Programmers. Implementation specific questions are off-topic here. This question is on-topic for Stack Overflow but it appears you've already posted it there. Please don't crosspost. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: You should have a sample line such as `/opt/hal/9000/monitor` with 4 or more slashes in it; it should also be left unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

A sed solution:

```
sed '/.*\/.*\/.*\//{s#/##g}' file
```

If Perl is ok for you:

```
perl -F/ -ape '$_=@F>3?join"",@F:join "/",@F;' file
```

Comment: what is "{s#/##g}" mean? don't you think, if I replace it with nothing, it will delete the whole line instead of deleting only the '/'

Comment: Instead of using /, i used # as limitor. It will not delete the whole line, you can definitely test it against a sample file..

Comment: That regex will work on lines with three or more slashes, not just those with strictly three slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$/ s%/%%g'
```

The gruesome pattern looks for start of line, a sequence of zero or more non-slashes followed by a slash, more non-slashes and a second slash, more non-slashes and a third slash, more non-slashes and the end of line.  On any line that matches that, substitute the slashes by nothing globally.

There are other ways to write the regex, but they aren't substantially clearer.  This will work in pretty much any version of `sed`.  So will this:

```
sed -e '/^\([^\/]*\/\)\{3\}[^\/]*$/ s%/%%g'
```

It looks for start of line, 3 units of (zero or more non-slashes followed by a slash), zero or more non-slashes and end of line.

If your `sed` has extended regular expressions (GNU `sed`, for example), then you can gain some notational convenience.

```
sed -r -e '/^([^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*$/ s%/%%g'

sed -r -e 's%^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$%\1\2\3\4%'
```

The latter captures the four sets of 'zero or more non-slashes' and pastes them together to make the replacement.  You could write that with the non-extended regular expressions, but it would be even more laden with backslashes than before.

Answer (score -1):

This is much simpler in `awk`:

```
awk -F/ 'NF==4 { gsub("/","") } {print}' tmp.txt
```

Comment: A comment to the answer by Guru indicates that the program must be sed.